# affine Gauss map of Hypersurface Manifold finite

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $M \subset \mathbb{C}^n $ be an algebraic $n-1$-dimensional manifold given as vanishing hypersurface of a polynomial $F \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$ of degree $d \ge 2$. The smoothness of $M$ can be characterized in pure algebraic terms by requiring that the *gradient / normal vector* $n_M(p):= (\frac{dF}{dx_1}(p), ..., \frac{dF}{dx_n}(p))$ is not zero for every $p \in M$. Note that since we assumed that $F$ has degree $d \ge 2$, $M$ is not a linear subspace and therefore $n_M(p)$ is not constant. We call $M \to \mathbb{C}^n, \ p \mapsto n_M(p) $ the Gauss map.

Question: Why is it true that the restriction of the gradient $n_M$ to every algebraic curve $C \subset M$, ie $1$-dimensional algebraic submanifold, is not constant? I found a projective form of this claim in J. Harris' First Course in Algebraic Geometry at the end of page 188. There is clamed that the Gauss map

$$ \mathcal{G}_M: M \to \mathbb{P}^{n*}, \ \ p \mapsto [\frac{dF}{dx_1}(p): ... : \frac{dF}{dx_n}(p)]$$

is finite. Obviousy that's equivalent to the claim avove that no curve is contracted to a single point.

What I tried so far: the claim is that to every algebraic curve $C \subset M$ the composition $ C \hookrightarrow M \xrightarrow{n_M} \mathbb{C}^n $ cannot be constant.

Let $p \in M$ and $C$ a curve embedded in $M$ through $p$. Since $C$ is a $1$-algebraic manifold We can $C$ parametrize locally via a chart map $c: (- \epsilon, \epsilon) \to C, t \mapsto c(t):= (c_1(t),..., c_n(t)), c(0)=p$, for appropriate polynomials $c_k(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$. Since $ C \subset M$, the composition $F \circ c: t \mapsto F(c(t))$ is zero and therefore it's derivative
$(F \circ c)'(t)= F'(c(t)) \cdot c'(t)$ is zero too. Note that $F'(p)= n_M(p)$ and $c'(t)$ is a non-zero tangent vector of $M$ at $c(t)$.

We obtain the non suprising fact that the normal vector $F'(p)=n_M(p)$ of $M$ is perpendicular to tangent vector $c'(t)$ along the curve $c(t)$. Assume that $n_M(p)$ is constant along $c(t)$.

If we can show that every curve $C$ in $M$ through $p$ is not contained it the affine space $p+ T_p M \cong p +\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, we win but I not see any plausible reason for this to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly false. Consider the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\Bbb C^3$. (Any developable ruled surface will do.)

Comment: yes, your counterexample of course works, but it leaves a queasy feeling on my understanding of the Gauss map. So far I know the dual manifold $M^*$ of a hypersurface manifold $M \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ (in fact this works for more general varieties as ong as they are 'nice' enough, but let ignore it here), which is by definition the union of the tangent planes of $M$ in $\mathbb{G}(n, n-1) \cong \mathbb{P}^{n*}$ - or in other words the image of $M$ by the Gauss map - has the same dimension as $M$, therefore the Gauss map should be finite. But doesn't it contradict to the observation

Comment: from your example that the claim above is wrong? Or is here the 
main point that the Gauss map is only *generically(!)* finite? But as far I see, in your example with the cylinder the Gauss map is even not generically finite, the lines parallel to $z$-axis are all mapped to same tangent space...

Comment: Indeed, Harris (along with Griffiths) has written papers on varieties with degenerate Gauss mappings. I’ll take a look at the result you’re citing later.

Comment: Harris is discussing smooth *projective* varieties, whereas your question was about affine varieties. Note that the projective closure of my cylinder is singular — it’s a cone over a smooth conic.

Comment: so here the issue is of global nature. Ok, so say we consider $M \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ as projective vanishing variety of $F$ now. Then the smoothness of $M$ is equivalent to that the value $n_M(p):=[\frac{dF}{dx_1}(p): ... : \frac{dF}{dx_n}(p)]$ is well defined in projective space and therefore it's just equivalent to the statement that the Gauss map $\mathcal{G}_M: M \to \mathbb{P}^{n*}, p \mapsto n_M(p)$ is well defined. Why in the *projective* case with smooth $M$, if we consider the composition $C \hookrightarrow M \xrightarrow{n_M} \mathbb{P}^n$ for a curve $C$, the map is not constant?

Comment: what we know for projective case is that this map is closed, so the image closed, but why it cannot be a point?

Comment: The embedding map 
$C \hookrightarrow M $
is given by $c \mapsto G(c):=[G_0(c):... G_n(c)]$ like any 
projective map for 
some homogeneous polynomials $G_i$, therefore
every $\frac{dF}{dx_i} \circ G$ is homogeneous too and 
since $G(c) \in M$ there exist for every $c$ at least one 
$\frac{dF}{dx_i} \circ G$ with $\frac{dF}{dx_i} \circ G(c) \neq 0$, so this map is
well defined on $C$.
Therefore the question becomes why 
$ c \mapsto [\frac{dF}{dx_1}\circ G(p): ... : \frac{dF}{dx_n}\circ G(c)]$
cannot be constant on $C$?

Comment: Basically, after a projective change of coordinates, you’re intersecting $C$ with $n$ hypersurfaces, so generically you expect at most finitely many solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow your. Clearly the intersection of general
 n hypersurfaces with C is empty. But why this fact implies that the map
 above cannot be constant? Could you maybe explain why the later 
statement is an immediate consequence of the former? Sorry, I'm a 
little too dumb at the moment to see the geometric connection ...

Comment: ...in the book Harris says that the curve is not mapped to a 
point basically because the derivatives $\frac{dF}{dx_i}$ not 
simultaneously vanish at any point of $X$ (well. that's just 
the assumption). But why this implies that the map restircted 
to the curve is non constant. I'm not pretty sure, maybe that's 
a reformulation of your  argument with generic non 
existence of solutions of intersection of $C$ with $n$ hyperplanes,
 but I'm not sure...

Comment: think I see now what you mean in your last comment:  do you interpret there the fibers of the morphism $C \hookrightarrow M \xrightarrow{n_M} \mathbb{P}^n$ as intersections of $C$ with $n$ hypersurfaces , right? More precisely, if $a_c=[a_0: a_1,...:a_n]$ is the image of a $c \in C$ you wanted to say that the fiber of $a_c$ is nothing but the intersection of $C$ with hyperplanes $a_0 \cdot \frac{dF}{dx_i} -a_i \cdot \frac{dF}{dx_0}$ obtained as images of the generators $a_0x_i- a_ix_0$ of the maximal ideal of $a_c$. Or do you refer there to an other facet of the problem?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking of making a projective change of coordinates to make the point $[1,0,\dots,0]$, and then I was just setting $\partial F/\partial x_i = 0$, $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: alright, so the correct statement should be that a *general* curve inside $M$ is not projected to point? Or could we get a stronger one? The reason why I'm still struggling a bit with the issue, is because Harris wrote at the end of p 188 that this Gauss map cannot be constant along a curve. Does he mean that this holds really for *every* curve contained in $M$ or only for a general curve? Your argument before shows this as far as I understand for general case and the natural question is if there some 'evil' curves exist dancing a little out of line.